# customize application with xml java

Tags: java, xml, customization, jdom

I write applications that need alot of options. These options can be handed to the application by a xml file. Theses files are quite big with some levels and a few dependancies not modelable in a schema.

So the file passes the jdom schema check. Now I want to create some config object for the application and set some variables in some classes.

I don't really see any way not hardcoding the names of the elements and attributes and then looping over these elements and creating new objects.

This makes a 20kLoc application have 25 classes only holding configurations for other classes.

Is there some golden hammer rule how to use xml and customize applications. It comes down to putting the information in the file into some lists, hashtables and attributes of objects.

Can that be done easier? Some awesome framework, maybe? Reflection? Beans? Beans is just a hype word for java programming, or am I missing something?

Comment: Any application should have a concise goal... The ratio of options vs feature should be balanced or there must be more features than options to add .... i guess you should start focusing on what is important in your program and what is not .... are your users going to use all the options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who controls the schema of the configuration files? If you can change it, you can simplify it enough to limit the number of classes needed.

If they are imposed from the outside, you might get some traction with Apache Commons BeanUtils and Betwixt.

Comment: The schema is only used to configure alot of applications via web, and make it nearly impossible to put in invalid entries. But I don't see how I could limit my classes with that. I need all these options, and to keep concerns separated I use differnt classes.

Comment: @Franz Kafka: BeanUtils allows to represent Java objects which are essentially key-value maps as valid beans to other frameworks that require Java beans. In that case you don't actually have to declare new classes for them. But the more I read your question and your comments, the more I think that complexity of your application may as well justify 25 configuration classes.

Comment: Okay I'm happy if i'm not doing something completely wrong. It only looks quite repetative always calling these same two/three lines of jdom code and create individual objects. But this can't be fitted into some awesome function genericly creating my classes.

Comment: @Franz Kafka: If the issue is actual parsing, not defining the configuration classes, you might consider looking at XStream or Digester. When you use these libraries, you just describe how XML should be mapped to the objects of your classes, rather than parsing XML node by node, creating objects and assigning properties.